# Use latest Python version on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Google Colab has Python 3.6 installed but it's not the current version of Python.

How would I go about upgrading Python to the latest version on Google Colab?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install Python 3.8 kernel in Google Colaboratory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The FAQ says:](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html)

> Colaboratory supports Python 2.7 and Python 3.6. We're aware that
>   users are interested in support for other Jupyter kernels (eg R or
>   Scala). We would like to support these, but don't yet have any ETA.

So I don't think its possible as of now.

Comment: The FAQ doesn't really say any of this at this time. As such, this answer is currently incorrect. The version of Python that's supported is still 3.6.

Comment: @Acumenus It was a period-specific answer to a period-specific question.

Comment: The answer can be deleted because it has no hope of being updated to be correct.