# math.prod() is not working in google colab notebook

Tags: python, math, sequence, product, iterable

I have executed this code in Gooogle ColabNotebook...As per the link given below...
prod() is available under math module. But why prod() is not working..its giving me the error?
https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_prod.asp

```
import math 
print(math.prod([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
```

Output
AttributeError: module 'math' has no attribute 'prod'

Comment: What version of python is your notebook? Is it less than 3.8?

Comment: Google Colab uses Python 3.6. 9 as of 2021. and ```math.prod``` is in python 3.8 version

Comment: If you motivation is to do "factorials" (as it might be from your example), you can use `math.factorial(7)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.prod()` is a new function available in Python versions 3.8 and later. Google Colab's kernel, as of this writing, [runs Python 3.6.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65912429/as-of-2021-which-python-version-is-google-colab-using#:%7E:text=Google%20Colab%20uses%20Python%203.6,9%20as%20of%202021.). As such, `math.prod()` won't be available for your use.

You can try to [install a Python 3.8 kernel in Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775160/install-python-3-8-kernel-in-google-colaboratory), but it seems some folks have some mixed results, and the method in the accepted answer is a bit hacky, but might work for your purposes.

Comment: Thank You so much..i appreciate your way of telling this answer

Answer (score 1):

Google Colab uses Python 3.6. 9 as of 2021. and `math.prod()` is in python 3.8 version

you can use this

```
from functools import reduce
import operator

print(reduce(operator.mul, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 1))
```