# Google Colab does not find new PyPi package

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, pypi

I just uploaded my new package to `PyPi`. It is available [here](https://pypi.org/project/mygalaxy).

I am trying to install it from Google Colab as usual by doing

`!pip install mygalaxy`

I get an error message saying:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
> mygalaxy (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
> for mygalaxy

I am wondering why is this happening, e.g. is there a lag between uploading packages to pypi and when these packages become available? This is [the only related information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71542700/how-to-install-latest-versions-of-packages-on-google-colab-exists-on-pypi-but) I could find about it but I it should need more context (explanation) to answer my question.

Comment: Colab uses python 3.7.13 while your project requires python 3.9 or higher. You need to either upgrade python and the kernel on Google Colab or to install It using, for instance, conda